# Different Approvers group for subsite on publishing portal

Tags: publishing, approval-process

I have a site collection with Publishing with Approval turned on. I have a requirement that a subsite within that site collection have approvals handled by a different set of people than are in the default Approvers group on the site collection root. I've broken permissions, created a 'Subsite Approvers' group on the subsite and assigned it the Approve permission level, but cannot think of a way to associate that group with the Publishing Approval workflow. It still notifies the members of the site collection root Approvers group.

Is it possibly to configure that with the OOTB Publishing Approval workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. Navigate to you subsite that you want a unique approvers group for.

Go to Site Actions > View All Site Content > Click the Pages library (or any library you want this for)

Then open the Library Ribbon Tab > List Settings > Workflow Settings and click the Page Approval workflow that should be there on Publishing Sites with Approval.

Now here is the part I never seems to notice:

Click Next at the bottom of the form. This brings up the Workflow Initiation form that has an Approvers parameter, preset to the default Approvers group. If you change it to the SharePoint group you prepared for the particular subsite you are on, it will only affect the workflow associated with the Pages library.

Yay!