# handling approvers group with multiple publishing sites

Tags: 2010, publishing-page

Ive set up a publishing site with workflow and have successfully submitted a page to be approved.  I noticed that when the site was provisioned it creates an approvers group which it did not assign to the site.  I then created another publishing site and noticed it was using the same approvers group for submission.  Im a bit confused with this.  How can i have multiple publishing sites in the same site collection that use different groups to handle approval and rejections.  I ask because different sites will require different approvers.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple.

Go to your library/list -> ribbon -> list settings -> Workflow Settings. You will see the option for setting the approval workflow.

Here is the same post which will give you the full solution
[Different Approvers group for subsite on publishing portal](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58794/different-approvers-group-for-subsite-on-publishing-portal)